# How to access jQuery plugin settings in public plugin method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a jQuery plugin using the following boilerplate:

https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js

My question is, if I have additional public methods in my plugin, how do I access the plugin's settings (and other variables) from within that public method?

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = "myplugin",
    defaults = {
        propertyName: "value"
    };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin ( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    var body = $('body');

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            // Init code here
        },
        yourOtherFunction: function () {
            // This is a private method
        }
    };

    // Toggle menu opening
    $.fn.doSomething = function(){
        // How do I access the plugin's settings here?  <<<<<<< Here is the issue
    };

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
        this.each(function() {
            if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
            }
        });

        // chain jQuery functions
        return this;
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

So, after instaniating my plugin using `$('.myelement').myplugin();` later I can do `$('.myelement').doSomething();` and in that method, I need to be able to access the plugin's settings. How do I do that? `this.settings` didn't appear to work.

Is there a better alternative plugin boilerplate or is this one pretty standard?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad design. You are creating a completely new plugin. And there is no connection between `myplugin` and `doSomething`.

I would suggest you to do this:

```
$.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
    if(options == 'doSomething'){
       // do something here or call some predefined function here
    }
    else{
    this.each(function() {
        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
            $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
        }
    });
    }
    // chain jQuery functions
    return this;
};
```

So, if you use the above construct, after calling `$('.myelement').myplugin();`, you can do:

```
$('.myelement').myplugin('doSomething');   //this is cool!
```

Comment: You are passing a string instead of options upon instantiation. Is that right? How do other plugins do it where they have multiple publicly accessible methods?